# Nesting Folders in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Is there a possible way to nest folders in Windows 7 (maybe a library) and have Windows Media Center point to one IE Movies folder from two different drives? I really don’t want to RAID my drives just for this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, adding multiple directories to a library entry is exactly what this new Windows 7 feature  was trying to accomplish. You add multiple directories to one category in your library, and then have all the files be accessible from one link. To add a folder, navigate to it, right-click and pick "add to library". [Here's one overview link.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/libraries)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading this right, you just want to add folders to your libraries.  This is quite supported by Microsoft out of the box - e.g. see their documentation [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Include-folders-in-a-library).  Basically, you just navigate to the folder that you want to add to the library, and then click on the "Include in Library" button.

If you want a more general solution to make multiple folders look like they are in one hierarchy, I would look at one of the tools that lets you create symlinks, such as [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) or [junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768).

However, you should also clarify what you mean by `I really dont want to raid my drives because of the failure` . . . I'm guessing you mean that you don't want to set them up as RAID0 so that if one goes, you don't lose both.  But if one goes, you still lose one.  Lack of RAID is not a backup, anymore than RAID is a backup.